# Why is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \binom{n}{s}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^{s}=\frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!}$?

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

For some $s\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $\lambda\in \mathbb{R^{+}}$

Why is

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\displaystyle \binom{n}{s}}{n^{s}}=\frac{1}{s!}?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: This is just a ratio of two polynomials in $n$ of degree $s$. The answer is clearly the ratio of their leading coefficients and is thus $1/s!$.

Comment: @PavelIevlev: why do we need a complicated Stirling approximation for this trivial result?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Sorry. When it comes to limits with factorials (or gamma-functions) Stirling formula is the first thing that pops in your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prove that
$$
a_n := \frac{n!}{n^s (n-s)!} \to 1
\qquad
n\to +\infty.
$$
You see in a moment that
$$
a_n = \frac{n (n-1) \cdots (n-s+1)}{n^s}
= \prod_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{n-k}{n}
= \prod_{k=0}^{s-1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
and so $a_n \to 1$ as $n\to +\infty$ since each of the $s$ factors goes to $1$.